# How to save and use only a particular package from Modelica library?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'm exploring an open-source Modelica library available on GitHub. Within this library, there's a "Media" folder containing various mediums such as air, refrigerants, etc. However, I'm specifically interested in utilizing the refrigerant folder and not the entire library for any other functionality.

My approach was to copy the refrigerant folder to another location and attempt to open it in Dymola. However, I encountered an error message preventing successful execution. The error message is as follows: [image: Dymola error]

How to effectively isolate and utilize just the refrigerant package from this Modelica library in Dymola?

Comment: I am not used to Dymola but the error text seems to be a "security error" rather than a "true error". But I have experience with cutting out a piece of library and make it work. A key question is if that Github library is dependent on Modelica Standard Library (MSL) and if so what version. Here is a transition from 3.2.3 to 4.0 during the last year or longer. So if there is a dependence to MSL for you Github library you must ensure that Dymola runs with the same version of MSL.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that you copy some files which are part of a larger library in the filesystem. You can read up in `within` in Modelica.

My suggestion is that you open the entire downloaded library in Dymola, then you right-click on the media library you want to copy and select `New>Duplicate Class`. That will create a clean copy.

Comment: Note that the Duplicated class _may_ still depend on other classes in the original library.